# Como utilizar tabs com itens dentro de um mesmo xml sem utilizar fragments?

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu tenho uma **Activity** onde vou precisar apenas de **2 abas**, uma que vai abrir logo de cara contando uma história utilizando textview simples, e outra sobre membros de uma equipe utilizando gridview.

Eu não queria utilizar fragments neste caso, então pensei em colocar as tabs no topo, e os layouts abaixo onde eu poderia alternar utilizando **visibility VISIBLE e GONE**

Pensei em algo no estilo tab onclicklistner, mas não sei como fazer isto com tabs, e os exemplos que encontro no google não mostra uma solução para isto.

Pensei também em usar tabhost, mas não entendo como funciona, pois quando coloco no meu xml ele não aparece quando executo o app.

Alguém poderia me ajudar com essa solução se caso for possível?

Se tiver um jeito de pegar o id da tab ao clicar me ajudaria muito.

**A estrutura que eu fiz esta assim:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E o XML está assim:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/SobreLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.teste.teste.SobreFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabsobrepagesitens"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabitem_sobre_historia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Nossa história" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:id="@+id/tabitem_sobre_equipe"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Equipe" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_sobre_historia"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabsobrepagesitens">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="Texto Sobre nós"
            android:textColor="@color/DarkPagesColor"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gv_sobre_equipe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:importantForAutofill="auto"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabsobrepagesitens">

    </GridView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acabei resolvendo desta forma e deu certo:

```
final ConstraintLayout clhistoria = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.cl_sobre_historia);
    final GridView gvequipe = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gv_sobre_equipe);

    TabLayout tabsobreitens = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsobrepagesitens);
    tabsobreitens.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch(tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    clhistoria.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    gvequipe.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
                case 1:
                    clhistoria.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    gvequipe.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }
    });
```

Mesmo assim de alguém conhecer outras formas e puder compartilhar eu agradeço.